# access windows shared drive from linux using FTP in Java

Tags: java, linux, windows, ftp

I am running my Java App on linux machine. I have an requirement to write the files to windows shared path. Requirement is mounting of drive from linux to windows can not be done and no additional libraries like JCIFS can be used. I thought of using FTP. Linux machine support FTP. I tried to use FTPClient which connects to the same machine where my app is running.(I do agree that this does not make sense). Running the FTP client in the same machine. How can I able to transfer the files to windows drive from linux?

App-> Running on Server-> writes file to some location

I want to copy file from that location(linux) to windows drive without using mounting concept and additional libraries?

Machine where this app is running supports FTP. I am connecting to the same machine using FTPClient which I don't think has any meaning. But I 
am stucked on this. I do not have much idea about linux environment and the way the files is accessed.

My Code is as follows: Would you please kindly suggest me what to do in this situation? Your Help will be highly appreciable.

```
    public static void downloadFile(String server, String userName, String password, String remoteFilePath, String localFilePath) {
        remoteFilePath="/tmp/"; //linux path where [My app is running on linux environment.]
        localFilePath="\\\\host\\folder\\subfolder\\"; //This is where I need to transfer files from linux machine. [It is shared path]

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server);

            ftpClient.login(userName, password);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localFilePath);
            System.out.println("Start Transferring  file...");
        boolean isCompletedDownload=    ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, fos);
            System.out.println("File Transfer!!!" + isCompletedDownload);
    //      ftpClient.deleteFile(remoteFilePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not clear what your question is. You have some code which is great, but it's not clear how you are stuck - where you're having problems, or if you're just looking for feedback on your approach. Are you getting an error? What error and where? How have you attempted to get past it?

Comment: My requirement is to copy files from linux system to windows shared path. My Java Application is running on linux. Its something like copying file from **/tmp/abc.txt** to **\\server\sharedfolder\abc.txt** but without using mounting and additional libraries like JCIFS in Java. I am trying to use FTP as the linux machine supports FTP. But How can it be achieved using FTP Client on the same linux machine to transfer files to windows shared drive.

Comment: This also sounds very similar to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042398/access-windows-drive-from-linux-unix?s=3|0.0000)